# What charges can be filed against someone who destroys evidence out of suspected negligence?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, canada, prosecution

### Background context

In instances of assault and sexual abuse at nightclubs, CCTV footage is a crucial source of information since most people present are likely to be intoxicated.

Please consider the following hypothetical scenario, the owners of a nightclub neglect to save or export evidence from CCTV footage because they don't care or are dishonest (for example, they don't want the police involved at their venue, which could result in lengthy investigations and financial losses).

> *"Sorry, but it appears I have accidentally lost all footage of the assault due to IT issues."*

### Question about this

If such a scenario were to occur, what charges could be brought against individuals who engage in this type of behavior? Are there any realistic actions that victims can take in response to this?

Comment: I'm going to assume based on the number of downvotes to this question that pretty much nothing can be done to realistically tackle scenarios such as these. I guess victims of simple & sexual assault are just going to get thrown under the bus. 

Comment: I wish that any downvoters would leave a comment indicting what they think is wrong with this question. In the absence of a comment, the poster cannot improve the post, others cannot edit it to fix the issue, and readers have no idea why someone objects to the post. Such a downvote seems pointless.

Comment: I for one don't think there is anything wrong with asking about this sort of situation. However, it is best to focus clearly on a single question here.

Comment: Is there anything to support the claim that "*some nightclub owners neglect to save or export evidence from CCTV footage because they don't care or are dishonest*"

Comment: @Rick Are you suggesting that the inverted claim *"all nightclub owners readily comply with law enforcement requests"* to be a more probable statement?

Comment: In your subject, you talk about negligence.  In your hypothetical, is the venue owner on notice that the footage from a particular date and time contains evidence of a crime?  Obviously, folks with CCTV cameras aren't under an obligation to retain video indefinitely in case someone subsequently wants it.

Comment: Your premise is that sexual assault investigations are so expensive for night clubs that they proactively ”misplace”  evidence in order to avoid it.  Given that destroying what you know to be evidence of a crime is in itself a crime, and one the night club managers would be guilty of but not the owner combined with the fact that the loss (if any) would be almost entirely loss wages, I think it is unlikely that night clubs have that many dedicated managers that are willing to take the fall so the company doesn’t spend a few hundred or thousand dollars in wages.

Comment: @jmoreno If the premise doesn't convince you, we can use our imagination to think of another situation where the person in question doesn't cooperate with the police for some reason. Also, not everyone makes logical game-theory decisions. If that were the case, crime wouldn't exist at all because of the severe consequences for perpetrators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You post contains 3 questions.

> What charges can be filed against someone who destroys evidence out of suspected negligence?

Your question says “suspected”, meaning it’s possible no crime was committed, and if one was committed, the authorities have no evidence of it.  They can do nothing.

Your second question describes a scenario where someone did so, but doesn’t address whether there is or is not evidence of them having done so.

> what charges could be brought against individuals who engage in this type of behavior?

Realistically, the answer to this question is also probably nothing, but theoretically there **could** be evidence of their activity and knowledge.  Maybe the destruction is caught on an internal CCTV where they first declaim their motivation and knowledge before destroying the evidence.  They could in that case be charged with the local equivalent to destruction of evidence [(for example nc 14-221.1)](https://www.ncleg.net/EnactedLegislation/Statutes/PDF/BySection/Chapter_14/GS_14-221.1.pdf) and probably obstruction of justice with a possible prison term of up to 10 months.

> Are there any realistic actions that victims can take in response to this?

Nearly the same answer as above, except that instead of being charged, the offender could be sued (by various people), the most likely basis would be Negligent Infliction of Emotional Distress.  It might be a bit of a stretch, but given evidence that they intentionally committed a crime (destruction of evidence that would have likely lead to a convict of the assault), not too much. It’s of course a bit easier because the plaintiff wouldn’t need to prove that they committed the act, just that it was more likely than not that they did.

In the comments you say “doesn’t cooperate with the police”, and nobody is going to be able to do anything about that (legally) as long as no crimes are committed as part of that non-cooperation.

Comment: This is the response that I had feared. The fact that our current judicial system does not allow the police to immediately seize incriminating evidence from complicit individuals like this is nothing short of a travesty. I will be writing to my attorney general to push for change.

Comment: @AlanSTACK: that would not change this answer for your suggested scenario at all, because in your scenario the evidence has already been destroyed.  If given full legal right to inspect the whole country and seize anything in it for any or no reason, they still aren’t going to find any evidence because it has already been destroyed.

Comment: @AlanSTACK: Also, you don’t ask what the police can do to prevent this, and the answer is simple: the police can seize the evidence after getting a warrant for it.  Which in todays world might take as little as 5 minutes.  It’s straightforward and just about incontestable.  An establishment with a CCTV camera that cover an area where a crime is alleged to have been committed is going to have to give up the video.